# He had not understood vs He did not understand

Tags: meaning, grammar, orthography, syntactic-analysis, single-word-requests

I'm a native Portuguese speaker and some time ago I heard someone say that it is **grammatically** wrong, in despite of everyday speaking, to construct sentences like "He had not understood" or "She does not made that", once in those cases it would be more correct to spell, respectively, "He did not understand" and "She did not make that". This confused me a lot because I read those first constructions everywhere I see English, as well as the second ones, therefore I would like to know the sight of English native speakers about the correctness or wrongness of those sentences.

Comment: Questions at this level are General Reference on ELU, but might be more suitable on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). @Karl - there's nothing wrong with *he had not understood*, ***in the right context***. But *she does not made that* is completely ungrammatical in ***any*** context.

Answer (score 3):

*He had not understood* and *he did not understand* are both grammatical and both idiomatic. They have slightly different meanings, (but in many contexts will be interchangeable).

*He had not understood* is what people now seem to call the *past perfect*, and is appropriate if the narrative time is in the past, and referring to a time before that at which he failed to understand.

*He did not understand* is less specific: it simply says that at some point in the past he either failed to understand or was in a state of not understanding (which might in turn relate to a communication further back).

The other case is different because **She does not made that* is not grammatical in any variety of English, as far as I know. If you meant *She does not make that*, that is perfectly grammatical, but has a different meaning from *She did not make that*.

Comment: "He had not understood" implies that he now does understand, while "he did not understand" does not, at least to my ear.

Comment: @Marc, I don't agree. It _can_ have that implication, but it doesn't necessarily: it depends entirely on context. I was thinking of a story like "John was in a mess. He was trying to assemble his new computer, but he had not understood the instructions".